# Where are start-up mobile network configuration files saved?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, 4g

After upgrading to OTA 13 when I start my mx5, the default mobile network speed is edge and not 4G as was previously the case. Where are start-up mobile network configuration files saved?

Brgds

Comment: I have already tried this but unsuccessfully. I 'm now looking for side « nmcli » or saved power options !

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings, select Mobile, then scroll down to the bottom where you will find the Connection type settings.